# What is the Best Way to Implement a Global Game Object in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, game-development

I made a Wordle clone made using React Native. Now, I'm working on adding a multiplayer version to it. My hope is to create an all-in-one Wordle clone with single-player and multiplayer game modes. You can see it here https://github.com/PoseidonCoder/tertle. (This is the initial singleplayer version). I made two custom headers for both game modes. Here's the singleplayer header:

```js
// SingleplayerHeader.jsx
import Settings from "./Settings";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { AntDesign, Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";
import styles from "../styles";
 
export default function SingplayerHeader({ game }) {
    const [showSettings, setShowSettings] = useState();
 
    return (
        <>
            <Settings
                answer={game.answer}
                visible={showSettings}
                onClose={() => setShowSettings(!showSettings)}
            />
 
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={game.back}>
                    <AntDesign name="caretleft" size={50} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
 
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>Wordle#{game.current}</Text>
 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={game.next}>
                    <AntDesign name="caretright" size={50} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
 
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setShowSettings(!showSettings)}>
                    <Fontisto name="spinner-cog" size={45} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </>
    );
}
```

I'm trying to grab the game object from props. But, I haven't actually created it yet. (It's just a placeholder). I want to share the game object/class between the headers and the rest of the components. Should I create a context for the entire game and wrap it around the route? Would I then be able to listen to changes? I'd also like the game object to be a class so that it's a bit easier to manipulate and more reusable. My hope is to reuse the game object for the single-player and multiplayer game modes. Should I create a singleton game class? I'm really just looking for the best way to implement this. I want a global variable class. Any help would be appreciated :).

```js
// App.js

import Singleplayer from "./src/screens/Singleplayer";
import SingleplayerHeader from "./src/components/SingleplayerHeader";
import MultiplayerHeader from "./src/components/MultiplayerHeader";
import Multiplayer from "./src/screens/Multiplayer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";
import Home from "./src/screens/Home";

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Singleplayer"
                    component={Singleplayer}
                    options={() => ({
                        headerTitle: () => <SingleplayerHeader />,
                    })}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="Multiplayer"
                    component={Multiplayer}
                    options={{ headerTitle: () => <MultiplayerHeader /> }}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for something like Redux or MobX. For multiplayer you're probably going to use sockets as well. Good luck!

Comment: Try a search for `react native state management`. There are lots of options and tradeoffs.